# logging on a remote machine

Tags: linux, shell

Is it possible to login to a particular folder of a remote machine, through shell script:
instead of ssh and then cd. Can I do it in one command?
Is it possible to copy a file on two different folders of a remote machine through scp in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `cp` command to ssh as follows:

```
ssh user@host "cp /path/to/folder1/file /path/to/folder2"
```

or combine with `cd`:

```
ssh user@host "cd /path/to/folder1; cp file /path/to/folder2"
```

Comment: It will execute command and disconnect you from remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no real solution to this.  You can try `ssh user@host bash -c "cd /tmp; bash -i"` if your shell is bash.  That will look a little like it could work, but you will quickly discover it's not really working.  (Try to invoke an editor such as vi and you will see.)

You can also put `cd /tmp` into the `~/.bashrc` on the remote end.  This way, `ssh user@host` does what you ask for.  But I guess you want to be able to go to different directories, so this won't fly either.

I think the best approach is to make it convenient to enter the `cd` command, e.g. using aliases.  Then it's less typing.

Comment: What is ssh user@host bash -c "cd /tmp; bash -i" command doing?

Comment: It connects to the remote host, and over there is changes to the `/tmp` directory and then invokes an interactive shell.  After this, you can do `pwd` to verify you are in fact in the right directory, and you can use `cd` and `ls` and so on.  But as I said, the illusion breaks down when you invoke an editor.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way for your first question is Expect:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@host
expect -re {\$ $} ;# adjust to suit your prompt
send "cd some/dir\r"
interact
```

I'm unclear about your 2nd question:  do you have 2 remote files that you want to copy to your local machine, or do you want to copy a file from one remote dir to another remote dir?

```
scp user@host:/path/to/file1 user@host:/path/to/file2 .
ssh user@host "cp /path/to/file1 /path/to/folder2/"
```